# "which" not able to locate packages installed with pip (WSL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've attempted to start writing Python in WSL, but the whole experience has been super messy. To install packages, I know I want to use pip3, but any pip3 commands result in

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'`

My work-around has been to use the following command to install, which *has* worked:

`python3 -mpip install --user somePackageName`

My real confusion now comes from the fact that the `which` command is not locating packages installed by the above command. However, I know they are there as they appear when I run 'python3 -mpip freeze'. Is this because they are installed locally?

(Also If anyone has experience with Python and pip in WSL and could weigh in on how to go about configuring my Python environment, in order to avoid these types of issues, that would be super helpful.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try: `python -m site`

(perhaps replacing `python` by `python3`, etc)

You should get a short output with the following block,

From Windows:

```
sys.path = [
    '<your current working directory>',
    'C:\\Python38a2\\python38.zip',
    'C:\\Python38a2\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Python38a2\\lib',
    'C:\\Python38a2',
    'C:\\Python38a2\\lib\\site-packages',
]
```

From WSL:

```
sys.path = [
    '<your current working directory>',
    '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
```

That's where you'll want to look for installed packages.

The order here is the import precedence (earlier entries "trump" later ones)

For `pip install`ed packages, you'll generally want to look in the `site-packages` directory.

For `<package manager> install`ed packages you'll generally want to look in the `dist-packages` directory.

Lastly, `which` is generally used to find *executables* on your `$PATH` environment variable (and, at least for me, requires that they have the executable bit set to appear in the results).

Here, you're looking for something different, modules or packages that are importable by Python.  In other words, modules or packages on your `$PYTHONPATH`.

These are two different types of "path"s.

Inside your interpreter, `$PYTHONPATH` maps to `sys.path` and `$PATH` maps to `os.environ['PATH']`.

Comment: Thank you--this is helpful. But for future reference, is there something I should do differently so that I can see my packages with `which` ?

Comment: I don't think so -- I'd suggest instead using `find`, e.g. `find / -name "*numpy*"`